# Insert data into database using LINQ

Tags: c#, sql, linq

I wrote a very simple method. It saves data from class `DayWeather` to the database. Method checks if line with that day exist in table and update her or create a new line.

I am doing it by adding new class for LINQ and move table from Server Inspector to the constructor. It generate new class `WeatherTBL`.

Method itself looks like this:

```
public static void SaveDayWeather(DayWeather day)
    {
        using (DataClassesDataContext db = new DataClassesDataContext())
        {
            var existingDay =
              (from d in db.WeatherTBL
               where d.DateTime.ToString() == day.Date.ToString()
               select d).SingleOrDefault<WeatherTBL>();
            if (existingDay != null)
            {
                existingDay.Temp = day.Temp;
                existingDay.WindSpeed = day.WindSpeed;
                existingDay.Pressure = day.Pressure;
                existingDay.Humidity = day.Humidity;
                existingDay.Cloudiness = day.Cloudiness;
                existingDay.TypeRecip = day.TypeRecip;
                db.SubmitChanges();
            }
            else
            {
                WeatherTBL newDay = new WeatherTBL();
                newDay.DateTime = day.Date;
                newDay.Temp = day.Temp;
                newDay.WindSpeed = day.WindSpeed;
                newDay.Pressure = day.Pressure;
                newDay.Humidity = day.Humidity;
                newDay.Cloudiness = day.Cloudiness;
                newDay.TypeRecip = day.TypeRecip;
                db.WeatherTBL.InsertOnSubmit(newDay);
                db.SubmitChanges();
            }
        }
    }
```

When I tried to call him from UnitTest project:

```
  [TestMethod]
    public void TestDataAccess()
    {
        DayWeather day = new DayWeather(DateTime.Now);
        DataAccessClass.SaveDayWeather(day);
    }
```

It write, that test has passed successfully. But if look into table, it has`t chanched.
No error messages shows. Does anyone know whats the problem?

P.S. Sorry for my bad English.

**UDP**
Problem was in that:
"...db maybe copied to the debug or release folder at every build, overwriting your modified one". Thanks @Silvermind

Comment: I am not sure why it is not storing the data. However your unit test is just calling the method but not using assert to validate the result.

Comment: @ARS, He don`t have result for validate. Method returns void. And I check the result into table...

Comment: I see. You can still write a method to retrieve the data and perform an assert. Anyway that is a different topic of discussion. Can you check the connection string to see if the data is inserted into the right db.

Comment: Besides the point offered by @ARS about the connection string, are your entity properties mapped?

Comment: @ARS, I use local db file and connection string look like this:`<add name="DataAccess.Properties.Settings.WeatherConnectionString"
            connectionString="Data Source=(LocalDB)\v11.0;AttachDbFilename=|DataDirectory|\App_Data\Weather.mdf;Integrated Security=True"
            providerName="System.Data.SqlClient" />`

Comment: And no another file in the folder.

Comment: @Silvermind, I use this tutorial for base http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb384428(v=vs.90).aspx and have`t see anything about entity properties mapping. Can your explain what it is?

Comment: If you did this `2.Drag the Customers node from Server Explorer/Database Explorer onto the O/R Designer surface.` than they are automatically mapped, but if you change anything int the database after that you should redo it, or change `Source` in the `dbml` `properties`-page for that `Entity`, Also: your db maybe copied to the debug or release folder at every build, overwriting your modified one. Are you also looking at the right file (Check your `Release/Debug` folder)?

Answer (score 9):

I wrote simple method to save employee details into Database.

```
private void AddNewEmployee()
{
    using (DataContext objDataContext = new DataContext())
    {                
        Employee objEmp = new Employee();
        // fields to be insert
        objEmp.EmployeeName = "John";
        objEmp.EmployeeAge = 21;
        objEmp.EmployeeDesc = "Designer";
        objEmp.EmployeeAddress = "Northampton";                
        objDataContext.Employees.InsertOnSubmit(objEmp);
        // executes the commands to implement the changes to the database
        objDataContext.SubmitChanges();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Please try with lambda expression. In your code, **var existingDay** is of type **IQueryable** 
In order to insert or update, you need a variable **var existingDay** of **WeatherTBL** type.
Hence try using below..

```
 var existingDay =
 db.WeatherTBL.SingleOrDefault(d => d.DateTime.Equals(day.Date.ToString()));

 if(existingDay != null)
  {
   //so on...
  }
```

Hope it should work..

Answer (score 0):

**Linq to SQL**

```
        Detail tc = new Detail();


        tc.Name = txtName.Text;
        tc.Contact = "92"+txtMobile.Text;
        tc.Segment = txtSegment.Text;
        var datetime = DateTime.Now;
        tc.Datetime = datetime;
        tc.RaisedBy = Global.Username;
        dc.Details.InsertOnSubmit(tc);

        try
        {


            dc.SubmitChanges();
            MessageBox.Show("Record inserted successfully!");
            txtName.Text = "";
            txtSegment.Text = "";
            txtMobile.Text = "";

        }


        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            MessageBox.Show("Record inserted Failed!");

        }
```